# how to find flash object id in youtube?

Tags: java

i have written code for automation testing on Flex Apps using Selenium Flash API - Webdriver. i ran the code but it says:
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: TypeError: document.movie_player is undefined`
i have defined movie_player argument in FlashObjectDriver.

```
public class flashWebdruver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:/Andriodtudio/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        FlashObjectWebDriver flashobj = new FlashObjectWebDriver(driver,"movie_player");

        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRjq9IUEjDM");

        Thread.sleep(10000L);
        flashobj.callFlashObject("pauseVideo","movie_player");
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        flashobj.callFlashObject("playeVideo","movie_player");
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        flashobj.callFlashObject("seekTo","90","playVideo","movie_player");
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        flashobj.callFlashObject("mute","movie_player");


    }

}
```

may be i have put wrong flash object id of youtube, but i caanot understand what i have made the mistake.

Comment: It's 2019, does Youtube even support Flash any more?

Comment: i know, but i don't have any idea about this test actually. i am in learning process. can please tell me then how can i find the object id and define it in code?